# How to edit my existing JS script to upload form when submit is clicked?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, codeigniter

Here is the code. What I want is to be able to upload the file and then also, the form is returning its url which is being added in the database for the particular user uploading the file. Actually its his profile picture so it's obvious it has to be connected, if you know what I mean.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#writer_reg").submit(function(){

            $("#writer_reg button").button('loading');
            $("#success").hide();
            $("#error").hide();

            var faction = "<?php echo site_url('writer/create')?>";
            var fdata = $("#writer_reg").serialize();
            $.post(faction, fdata, function(rdata){
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(rdata);
                if(json.isSuccessful){
                    $("#successMessage").html(json.message);
                    $("#success").show();
                }else{
                    $("#errorMessage").html(json.message);
                    $("#error").show();

                }

                $("#writer_reg button").button('reset');
                $("#writer_reg input[name='name']").select();
            });

            return false;
        });
    });


    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? This piece of javascript doesn't have anything to do with what you want. I don't think you can expect people to write the code for you, especially if you don't show any effort yourself.

Comment: Yes. I have tried a couple of things. But they wont work. I know I have to add something in this one to make it work and I have been tirelessly trying for hours; to no avail. This piece of java script is uploading my form data that is text and other stuff while form is being submitted. However, the file wont get uploaded at all. If you know, you can help. Otherwise, dont bother clicking on questions.

Comment: How am I supposed to know if I can help before clicking on the question? Here's [a link](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/) that may be useful in solving your problem.

Comment: That's the script I've tried , to no avail. I havent posted it here though as it's not working

Comment: I think you should provide as much information as possible about what you have already tried, because as you can see you are wasting other people's and and your own time by not doing it.

Answer (score 2):

have you put your form on multipart data?

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```